# Python Convert to CSV with encoding type

Tags: python, pandas, csv, utf-8, tabula

Someone helped me with a program so that I can convert PDF files from that format to csv but they didn't specify an encoding type, Here is the code:

```
import os
import glob
import tabula

path="/Users/username/Downloads/"
for filepath in glob.glob(path+'*.pdf'):
    name=os.path.basename(filepath)
    tabula.convert_into(input_path=filepath, 
                        output_path=path+name+".csv",
                        pages="all")
```

How can I get the CSV files to be converted with the encoding to be `utf-8` or `cp1252`

Thanks for helping

Error I'm getting

[image: Error]

Comment: PDFs are binary files. You can't expect to be able to decode them with any text encoding, because they're not strictly text.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `chardet` library to get the resulted encoding of the file generated by tabula, and then `pandas` to convert to the encoding you want.

```py
import chardet
import pandas as pd

for filepath in glob.glob(path+'name.csv'):
    with open(filepath, 'rb') as f:
        result = chardet.detect(f.read())
    df = pd.read_csv(filepath,encoding=result['encoding'])
    df.to_csv(filepath,index=False,encoding='utf-8')
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer this seems promising but I'm getting a ParserError on line 7 `df = pd.read_csv(filepath,encoding=result['encoding'])`

Comment: Can you give me the exact error please ?

Comment: I just uploaded

Comment: Try this: `df = pd.read_csv(filepath,encoding=result['encoding'], encoding_errors='replace')`

Comment: Received error `TypeError: read_csv() got an unexpected keyword argument 'errors'` but when I run it on your updated version no errors but nothing seems to be updated

Comment: It's `encoding_errors` and not `errors`

Comment: Received another error with the original code but the edited same result nothing seems to be updated